# Comparação de Objetos

Tags: java, objetos

O código abaixo gera um `false`, porém os objetos possuem os mesmos valores de atributos, existe algum método que compara os objetos, porém seus atributos, e não o objeto em si?

```
Produto P5 = new Produto(1, 0, 10,1000.0,"Samsung","smartphone");
Produto P6 = new Produto(1, 0, 10,1000.0,"Samsung","smartphone");  
System.out.println(P5.equals(P6));
```

Comment: Não se esqueça de que as IDEs modernas (Eclipse, IntelliJ Idea) podem gerar o equals e o hashCode automaticamente para você.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O resultado da comparacão de objetos é feito através dos métodos `hashCode()` e `equals()`, da classe `Object`. Logo, para fazer a comparação do seu jeito você deve sobreescrever esses os métodos em sua classe `Produto`.

Criando uma classe Produto ao meu gosto (já que você não disse os nomes dos atributos), ficaria algo assim:

**Produto**

```
public class Produto {

    int idProduto;
    String nomeProduto;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //deve ser o mesmo resultado para um mesmo objeto, não pode ser aleatório
        return this.idProduto;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //se nao forem objetos da mesma classe sao objetos diferentes
        if(!(obj instanceof Produto)) return false; 

        //se forem o mesmo objeto, retorna true
        if(obj == this) return true;

        // aqui o cast é seguro por causa do teste feito acima
        Produto produto = (Produto) obj; 

        //aqui você compara a seu gosto, o ideal é comparar atributo por atributo
        return this.idProduto == produto.getIdProduto() &&
                this.nomeProduto.equals(produto.getNomeProduto());
    }   

}
```

O método `hashCode` é usado para agilizar a busca em [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), e sempre deve retornar um mesmo valor para um mesmo objeto, no caso acima preferi fazer o método retornar o `idProduto` pois se o `idProduto` for diferente nem adiante ir para o `equals()`, pois certamente ele retornará falso.

Comment: Não seria melhor ter os mesmos campos no equals e no hashCode? Um é o complemento do outro, e embora o equals seja quem dê a última palavra sobre o objeto ser o mesmo ou não, o ideal seria que o método hashCode também levasse o nome do produto em consideração - ou que o equals não usasse o nome do produto.

Comment: @RaviWallau não vejo motivos para fazer isso, como vc msm disse o equals dá a ultima palavra no resultado da comparação, inclusive nesse caso em especifico se não sobrescrever o hashCode ainda assim funcionara, mas eu preferi manter o [**contrato**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) que diz `to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes`. O `hashCode`, como disse na resposta, não tem a funcao de comparar, ele apenas serve para que agilizar as buscas em Collections.

Comment: Bom... Por via de regra eu sempre mantenho os mesmos campos em ambos os métodos, mais porque eu não vejo motivo para não fazer isso. Um bom hashCode é um hashCode que diminui ao máximo a chance de colisões, e no seu caso, as chances de colisão aumentam.

Comment: @RaviWallau entendo seu ponto, mas acredito que não existe uma regra que é a melhor em todos os casos. No caso acima estou usando o `idProduto` para definir o `hashCode`, acredito que o id seja único, caso não seja, realmente existirá um meio de implementar um `hashCode` melhor do que eu implementei. Mas para meios didáticos meu exemplo atende, já que eu cumpri o contrato do `equals`, do `hashCode` e sobrescrevi o método que gera o `hashCode` de uma forma que ele não seja o mais ineficiente possível, que seria o caso de retornar uma constate.

Comment: @RaviWallau Vc pode ir mais a fundo no assunto `como gerar um hashcode utilizando todos os atributos da classe` postando sua própria resposta, caso ache que seja relevante para a pergunta. Talvez seja uma boa, pois eu mesmo não costumo fazer isso com meu códigos _da vida real_, e futuros visitantes poderiam usufruir de tal informação.

Answer (score 2):

Você não está esquecendo de especializar o `equals` para `Produto`?

Deve ser algo do tipo:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (other == null) 
        return false;

    if (other == this)
        return true;

    if (!(other instanceof Produto))
        return false;

    Produto p = (Produto) other;

    // Aqui você implementa como deve se feita a comparação.
    // Verifica se os nomes dos produtos são iguais, ids e etc.

    if (p.id == this.id) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```